# Como remover espaços de uma string em Java?

Tags: java

Estou com uma dúvida a respeito de como fazer para remover espaços de uma string em Java, fazendo isso através do `for`.

Estou fazendo um diamante de letras, e uso uma variável para criar o espaço entre as letras.

```
                     A
                    B B
                   C   C
                  D     D
                 E       E
                F         F
               G           G
```

Eu consegui montar a parte de cima do diamante, porém é preciso fazer a de baixo, e preciso utilizar a variável que contem todos os espaços. Minha ideia é  pegar o espaço entre os 2 F e diminuir 2 espaços a cada laço até que chegue na letra A.

Se puderem me ajudar, agradeço, pois estou quebrando a cabeça para resolver esse problema simples.

Segue abaixo o código que fiz, ele ficou grande, pois sou novo em java e na programação em geral, e não tenho as técnicas ainda:

```
public class Diamante {
    public void MontarDiamante()
    {
        //PARTE SUPERIOR
String espaço = {" ", "  ", "   "...etc} // Coloquei 26 posições de espaços para cada uma das letras do alfabeto para criar os espaços que ficam do lado esquerdo de fora do diamante.
        int x = 0;      
        String espacoLetras = " ";

        String alfabeto[] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
        String letra = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Diamante de Letras\nInsira uma Letra: ");
        for(int c = 0; c < alfabeto.length; c++)
        {
            if(c == 0)
            {
                System.out.println(espacos[0]+alfabeto[0]);
            }
            System.out.println(espacos[c+1]+alfabeto[c+1]+espacoLetras+alfabeto[c+1]);
            espacoLetras = espacoLetras + "  ";
            if(letra.equals(alfabeto[c+1]))
            {
                x = c;
                break;              
            }
        }

        //PARTE INFERIOR DO DIAMANTE
        for(int i = x; i >= 0 ; i--)
        {
            espacoLetras = espacoLetras.trim();
            System.out.println(espacos[i]+alfabeto[i]+espacoLetras+alfabeto[i]);
            /*if(i == 0)
            {
                System.out.println(espacos[i]+alfabeto[i]);
            }*/

        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Diamante d = new Diamante();
        d.MontarDiamante();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seria mais fácil entender o que você está fazendo se você mostrasse o código que faz a metade superior. Fazer isso por susbstituição de espaços é possível, mas precisaria saber de quais variáveis você está falando.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Proponho as seguintes alterações na classe para obter o resultado desejado (explicações nos comentários dentro do código):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Diamante {

  private static final String[] ALFABETO = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

  public void montar(String escolhida) {
    int maximo = Arrays.binarySearch(ALFABETO, escolhida); // Encontra a posição da letra passada como parâmetro
    boolean par = (maximo % 2) == 0; // Verifica se o número é par ou impar para cálculo da posição
    int metade = Math.floorDiv(maximo, 2); // Encontra a posição onde ficará o meio do diamante
    String espacos = "               ".substring(0, metade); //Corta o número de espaços para realizar o espelhamento
    int posicao = 0; // Inicia o contador de posição

    for (int indice = 0; indice <= maximo; indice++) {
      String letra = ALFABETO[indice];
      StringBuilder construtor = new StringBuilder(espacos); // Monta um StringBuilder para substituição das letras
      String texto;

      // Se for a primeira posição ou a última não espelha o texto
      if (posicao == 0) {
        texto = espacos + letra + espacos;
      } else {
        construtor.setCharAt(posicao - 1, letra.charAt(0)); // Coloca a letra na posição correta dentro da String de espaços
        texto = construtor.toString();
        texto = this.inverter(texto) + " " + texto; // Inverte o texto obtido criando espelhamento
      }

      System.out.println(texto); // Imprime na tela

      if (indice < metade) { // Caso ainda não tenha passado da metade, coloca mais espaços
        posicao++;
      } else if (par || indice > metade) { // Caso tenha passado da metade ou seja par e esteja na metade começa a remover espaços
        posicao--;
      }
    }
  }

  public String inverter(String texto) {
    StringBuilder construtor = new StringBuilder(texto);

    return construtor.reverse().toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Diamante d = new Diamante();

    d.montar("H");
  }
}
```

A execução do código acima resulta em:

```
   A
  B B
 C   C
D     D
E     E
 F   F
  G G
   H
```

Veja funcionando no [**IDEone**](https://ideone.com/3tfDyw).

Answer (score 1):

Quero agradecer a todos que se prontificaram a me ajudar a solucionar o problema!

Eu consegui resolver o problema utilizando o substring que foi utilizado no código do amigo Sorack, coloquei ele dentro de um for e determinei que a cada loop ele corte 2 espaços que estão na variavel espacoLetras que guarda os espaços do diamante.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
int x = 0;  


    String espacoLetras = " ";
    String espacos[] = {"                         ","                        ","                       ","                      ","                     ","                    ","                   ", "                  ", "                 ",
     "                ", "               ", "              ", "             ", "            ", "           ", "          ", "         ", "        ", "       ", "      ",
     "     ", "    ", "   ", "  ", " ", "",};
    String alfabeto[] = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
    String letra = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Diamante de Letras\nInsira uma Letra: ");

    letra = letra.toUpperCase(); //Converter letra minuscula para maiuscula.

    if(letra.equals("A")) //Tratamento quando o usuário insere A, pois não possivel formar um diamante somente com A.
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Não é possivel montar um diamente somente com A!\nInsira uma letra depois de A!");
    }
    else
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < alfabeto.length; c++)
        {
            if(c == 0)
            {
                System.out.println(espacos[0]+alfabeto[0]);
            }
            System.out.println(espacos[c+1]+alfabeto[c+1]+espacoLetras+alfabeto[c+1]);
            espacoLetras = espacoLetras + "  ";
            if(letra.equals(alfabeto[c+1]))
            {
                x = c;
                break;              
            }
        }
        //PARTE INFERIOR DO DIAMANTE
        int total_espaco = espacoLetras.length();
        total_espaco = total_espaco - 2;

        for(int i = x; i >= 1 ; i--)
        {
            total_espaco = total_espaco - 2; 
            espacoLetras = espacoLetras.substring(0, total_espaco);
            System.out.println(espacos[i]+alfabeto[i]+espacoLetras+alfabeto[i]);
            if(i == 1)
            {
                System.out.println(espacos[0]+alfabeto[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

E o código acaba exibindo o diamante da maneira que era pedido no enunciado.

```
                     A
                    B B
                   C   C
                  D     D
                 E       E
                F         F
               G           G
                F         F
                 E       E
                  D     D
                   C   C
                    B B
                     A
```

Answer (score 0):

Kelvera, entendi sua lógica, mas antes queria propor uma maneira que acho mais simples, não sei se encaixa no seu cenário. Ao invés de montar o diamante retirando os espaços, não seria melhor você começar de onde não tem espaço e ir adicionando?

```
String espaco = ' ';

String letras_array = 'ABCDEFG';
System.out.println(letras_array.charAt(0)); //Imprime a primeira letra

//For para imprimir o diamante
for (int i = 1; i < letras_array.length() ; i++){
  System.out.println(letras_array.charAt(i) + espaco + letras_array.charAt(i));
  espaco = espaco + '  '; //(para cada loop, ele vai adicionar dois espaços)
}
```

Isso encaixa no seu cenário?

Comment: Creio que não, pois a ideia é montar um diamante com uma letra inserida pelo usuário e com esta letra será definido o meio do diamante.

Comment: Coloque essa informação na pergunta, todas as respostas que podem ser formuladas para a sua pergunta não terão sequer idéia dessa informação omitida, e isso não as fazem erradas.